# MySQL Last_Insert_ID Syntax

Tags: php, mysql, last-insert-id

I have this code:

```
//insert user input into db
$query = "INSERT INTO test_details (test_title, user_id, likes)
VALUES ('$title', '$user_id', '0')";
$query .= "INSERT INTO test_descriptions (test_id, description)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$description')";
if(isset($grade) && isset($difficulty) && isset($subject)) {
    $query .= "INSERT INTO test_filters (test_id, grade, subject, difficulty)
    VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$grade', '$subject', '$difficulty')";
}
if(mysqli_multi_query($con, $query)) {
    echo 'Go <a href="../create">back</a> to start creating questions.';
}
else {
    echo "An error occurred! Try again later.";
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}
```

When I try executing the code I recieve this MySQL error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @id = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID())INSERT INTO test_descriptions (test_id, descr' at line 2` Not sure what was done wrong, all the syntax seems correct. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to add semi-colons between each of your separate SQL statements.

Comment: Your error message includes SQL fragments that don't appear in your code excerpt (`SET @id ...`).  Am I missing something or are you?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing semi-colons in your mutli-query statement.

You can add them in front of the queries you are concatenating (`.=`) for consistency, since the if statement may or may not add a query into the mix.

```
//insert user input into db
$query = "INSERT INTO test_details (test_title, user_id, likes)
VALUES ('$title', '$user_id', '0')";
$query .= ";INSERT INTO test_descriptions (test_id, description)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$description')";
if(isset($grade) && isset($difficulty) && isset($subject)) {
    $query .= ";INSERT INTO test_descriptions (test_id, grade, subject, difficulty)
    VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$grade', '$subject', '$difficulty')";
}
if(mysqli_multi_query($con, $query)) {
    echo 'Go <a href="../create">back</a> to start creating questions.';
}
else {
    echo "An error occurred! Try again later.";
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Or as andrewsi mentioned, the implode method:

```
//insert user input into db
$query[] = "INSERT INTO test_details (test_title, user_id, likes)
VALUES ('$title', '$user_id', '0')";
$query[] = "INSERT INTO test_descriptions (test_id, description)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$description')";
if(isset($grade) && isset($difficulty) && isset($subject)) {
    $query[] = "INSERT INTO test_descriptions (test_id, grade, subject, difficulty)
    VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$grade', '$subject', '$difficulty')";
}
if(mysqli_multi_query($con, implode( ';', $query ))) {
    echo 'Go <a href="../create">back</a> to start creating questions.';
}
else {
    echo "An error occurred! Try again later.";
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Comment: You can also add the separate statements to an array, and then `implode` it, using a semi-colon as glue.

Comment: Thank you for two solutions, I am used to using mysqli_query all the time. Will accept as correct answer.

Comment: Also, why add semi-colons in front of the queries? The code will work with semi-colons at the end.

Comment: True. I suppose it's OCD on my end. I need to Xdebug my head, could just end every query with it. I was thinking consistency with the least amount of characters.